# Use proposition 2 to prove proposition 1. Would you correct my proof?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

**PROPOSITION 1:**  If $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable map, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then a graphic of $f$, given by $(x, y, f(x,y))$, where $(x,y)\in U$ is a regular surface.

**PROPOSITION 2:** If $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable map and $a\in f(U)$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f^{-1}(a)$ is a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**DEFINITION:** Given a differentiable map $F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ defined in an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we say that $p\in U$ is a **critical point** of $F$ if the differential $dF_p:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is not a surjective (or onto) mapping. The image $F(p)\in \mathbb{R}^m$ of a critical point is called a **critical value** of $F$. A point of $\mathbb{R}^m$ which is not a critical value is called a **regular value** of $F$.

**MY ATTEMPT:**
Define $h:U\subset\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $h(x, y, z)= f(x, y)-z$ where $f$ is differentiable. Note that $$\nabla h = (h_x(x, y,z), h_y(x, y,z), h_z(x, y,z))= (f_x, f_y, f_z)=(f_x, f_y, -1) \implies \nabla h(p) \neq 0,\; \forall p.$$
Therefore, $(0,0,0)$ is a regular value of $h$. Now, note that

\begin{align*}
h^{-1}(0)&=\{(x, y, z); h(x, y, z)=0\}\\
&=\{(x, y, z); f(x, y)=z\}\\
&=\{(x, y, f(x, y))\}:=\text{graphic of}\; f
\end{align*}

Thus, by proposition 2, graphics of differentiable functions are regular surfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY ATTEMPT:**
Define $h:U\subset\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $h(x, y, z)= f(x, y)-z$ where $f$ is differentiable. Note that $$\nabla h = (h_x(x, y,z), h_y(x, y,z), h_z(x, y,z))= (f_x, f_y, f_z)=(f_x, f_y, -1) \implies \nabla h(p) \neq 0,\; \forall p.$$
Therefore, $(0,0,0)$ is a regular value of $h$. Now, note that

\begin{align*}
h^{-1}(0)&=\{(x, y, z); h(x, y, z)=0\}\\
&=\{(x, y, z); f(x, y)=z\}\\
&=\{(x, y, f(x, y))\}:=\text{graphic of}\; f
\end{align*}

Thus, by proposition 2, graphics of differentiable functions are regular surfaces.